# HBase not starting in standalone mode on Windows

Tags: java, windows, hadoop, hbase

I downloaded `HBase 1.0.1` on my Windows machine and wasn't able to get it to start.

I got the following error message:

```
C:\Users\admin\Downloads\hbase-1.0.1>bin\start-hbase.cmd
Error: Could not find or load main class " "
ERROR: Could not determine the startup mode.
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem in how it is forming the java arguments, specific to the memory options.

Work-around: Find the following line in hbase.cmd and **REMOVE** `%HEAP_SETTINGS%`.

```
set java_arguments=%HBASE_OPTS% -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" %CLASS% %hbase-command-arguments%
```