# how to configure for test hbase program

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, hbase, hadoop2

I'm new in hadoop and hbase and installed hadoop in windows8.
I start hadoop Like image and test map-reduce by word count program and it's work.(in eclipse)
[image]

But I can't use hbase! I use an hbase plugin for eclipse. (from eclipse marketplace site)
I have a class for connect and create table , ....

```
  public class HBaseConnector {

private static Configuration configuration = null;
private static HTable hTable;
private static HBaseAdmin admin;
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HBaseConnector.class);

static {
    configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create();
}

public void creatTable(String tableName, String[] familys) {

    try {
        admin = new HBaseAdmin(configuration);

        if (admin.tableExists(tableName)) {

            logger.debug(tableName + "table already exists !!");

        } else {

            HTableDescriptor tableDesc = new HTableDescriptor(tableName);
            for (int i = 0; i < familys.length; i++) {
                tableDesc.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor(familys[i]));
            }
            admin.createTable(tableDesc);
            logger.debug(tableName + " table created successfully !! ");

        }
        admin.close();

    } catch (MasterNotRunningException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    } catch (ZooKeeperConnectionException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

in main function I have these codes:

```
  String tablename = "employee";
        String[] familys = { "personal", "professional" };

        HBaseConnector connector = new HBaseConnector();
        connector.creatTable(tablename, familys);
```

but it can't connect :

```
    18:59:34 WARN zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper exception: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/master
16/03/18 18:59:34 INFO util.RetryCounter: Sleeping 4000ms before retry #2...
16/03/18 18:59:34 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (Unable to locate a login configuration)
16/03/18 18:59:34 ERROR zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO: Unable to open socket to 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181
16/03/18 18:59:34 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol family: connect
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.registerAndConnect(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:266)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.connect(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:276)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.startConnect(ClientCnxn.java:958)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:993)
16/03/18 18:59:34 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO: Ignoring exception during shutdown input
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
```

how I run a simple HBase program?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you forgot to install or start HBase. HBase is an extra component and from what I see is you run only HDFS and Yarn.

Your last log message says it's unable to connect to Zookeeper. It's a (distributed) key/value store for Hadoop components. Your simple HBase program is trying to connect to Zookeeper and get value `/hbase/master` znode. It fails doing this and thus it cannot continue and connect to HBase master.

Install HBase master + at least one RegionServer. If you follow install docs, you will deal with Zookeeper as well:

https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#standalone_dist

My personal advice: Use 1.1.3 instead of 1.2.0 unless you really need 1.2.0 for some reason. I had trouble starting 1.2.0.

Comment: I have an error in starting hbase:
d:\hadoop-2.3.0\hbase-1.1.3\bin>start-hbase.cmd
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hba......

org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseConfTool.  Prog
ram will exit.
ERROR: Could not determine the startup mode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203177/hbase-not-starting-in-standalone-mode-on-windows